# Pixelated text using external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I've a 3440 x 1440 external monitor hooked up to a MacBook Pro (Mid 2014).

It seems as if images are being displayed correctly, but text is highly rasterised, both in browsers and in native apps such as Finder. Any ideas as to what is causing the pixelation?

In terms of System Preferences > Displays, I'm using resolution 'Default for display' and in System Preferences > General I've toggled 'Use LCD font smoothing when available' on and off with no change.

Below is an image displaying the rasterisation:

[image]

Comment: 'Default for display' doesn't actually tell you what's being used as the current resolution. Switch to Scaled & it will show the actual figure - which I suspect is not what you're expecting it to be... & in fact [Everymac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.8-15-iris-only-mid-2014-retina-display-specs.html) tells me it's only capable of 2560x1600

Comment: On scaled I can put it on the 3440 x 1440 (same as monitor) and still text is pixelated.

Comment: Yet the machine cannot do 3440... so I'm somewhat puzzled... unless it's simply scaling up, badly.

Comment: The thing is, images and such seem to be ok in particular apps, whereas text seems to suffer throughout.